# Using UIScrollView with paging enabled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, paging, uicontrol

I have implemented paging using `UIScrollView` and adding `UIVIew` and `UIControls` in this `UIVIew` on each pages. Surprisingly none of the `UIControl` responding when it is on `UIScrollView` with paging enabled! Following is my code. Could anyone please tell me how to get `UIControls` working on `UIScrollView` with paging enabled?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int totalPages = [[delegate sections] count] + 2; // 2 for startOfDayQuestions and endOfDayQuestions

    int X = 45, Y = 20, H = 40, W = 680;

    // start of the day questions
    CGRect startFrame = scrollView.frame;
    startFrame.origin.x = 0;
    startFrame.origin.y = 0;

    UIView *startPage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, W, H)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = @"Text";
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:paragraph_font_name size:paragraph2_font_size];
    [startPage addSubview:label];

    Y += H;

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, W, H)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [startPage addSubview:textField]; --> This UITextField doesn't respond when added to startPage and in turns scrollView but works fine if I add it to self.view!

    // a page is the width of the scroll view
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * totalPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    pageControl.numberOfPages = totalPages;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    if (pageControlUsed)
        return;

    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender
{
    int page = pageControl.currentPage;

    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

    pageControlUsed = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding subScrollView with no pagingEnabled to each page and controls into subScrollView works! If you add controls directly to scrollview with paging enabled, it seems gesture recogniser's first responder is always scrollview so your controls never gets the event and behave like a disabled!